# Emacs: Is there a better PgDn/PgUp behaviour with cua-mode?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, cua, cua-mode

I'd like the <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> keys to just move the contents of the shown file upwards or downwards, but the cursor (*point* in Emacs Lingo) should stay where it is (on the screen). Unfortunately the default Emacs behaviour is different. The default behaviour is difficult to describe, but if you press <kbd>PgDn</kbd> followed by <kbd>PgUp</kbd> you don't end up where you were before (!).

This is not a new problem and there exists a nice solution called [sfp-page-up and sfp-page-down](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Scrolling) in the [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsWiki).

```
(defun sfp-page-up ()
  (interactive)
  (setq this-command 'previous-line)
  (previous-line
   (- (window-text-height)
      next-screen-context-lines)))
```

There is one problem, however, in combination with [cua](http://www.cua.dk/cua.html)-mode, which provides (among others) shift-selection (pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> and a Cursor movement key like <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>PgDn</kbd> starts highlighting a selected area):

`cua-mode` doesn't recognise the redefined <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> keys, i.e. they don't start a selection. The workaround is to press first the <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> key and then continue with <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>.

How can I make `cua-mode` play nicely with `sfp-page-up/down`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the other half of the solution in the thread [if I set home key (...) then shift+home does not select text in cua-mode](http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.emacs.help/browse_thread/thread/bd5fcbc1899d6dfb/acee806a1881e13a) on [gnu.emacs.help](http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.emacs.help):

To participate in the shift selection of `cua-mode`, a function (in my case `sfp-page-xxx`) must have the symbol property `CUA` set to `move`:

```
(put 'sfp-page-up 'CUA 'move)
```

(For the first half of the solution see [JSON's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513692/emacs-is-there-a-better-pgdn-pgup-behaviour-with-cua-mode#answer-4515471)).

So here is my complete solution:

```
(defun sfp-page-down (&optional arg)
  (interactive "^P")
  (setq this-command 'next-line)
  (next-line
   (- (window-text-height)
      next-screen-context-lines)))
(put 'sfp-page-down 'isearch-scroll t)
(put 'sfp-page-down 'CUA 'move)

(defun sfp-page-up (&optional arg)
  (interactive "^P")
  (setq this-command 'previous-line)
  (previous-line
   (- (window-text-height)
      next-screen-context-lines)))
(put 'sfp-page-up 'isearch-scroll t)
(put 'sfp-page-up 'CUA 'move)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you add `^` to start of the `(interactive "...")` spec (inside the double quotes) of the functions, they will support shift selection in Emacs 23.1 and later.

Comment: I changed the functions to `(defun sfp-page-down (arg) (interactive "^p") ...`, but they still can't start a selection. Should I patch cua-mode to `remap sfp-page-up` instead of `remap scroll-up`? BTW: which one is correct, `"^p"` or `"^P"`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's half of the solution. When I disable `cua-mode`, the shift selection now indeed works with `sfp-page-xx`. But with `cua-mode` enabled it still doesn't work yet.